# To what degree do airline ops specs preclude hand flying?

Tags: airline-operations

I retired in 1999. I'm curious to what degree typical airline ops specs now discourage or prohibit doing what I used to do as a matter of course insofar as hand flying.

For example, I usually hand flew the aircraft until leveling at the first cruise altitude (FL290 or FL310 on fully loaded 747-100/200 aircraft). For the step climbs as fuel was burnt, I nearly always disengaged the autopilot and did the climb manually. At the top of descent I clicked the autopilot off, and I flew approaches manually.

Many of my fellow crew members thought it odd that I did so much hand flying, but as I would explain when asked, I didn't get to the 747 until I was 50 and didn't get to its left seat until a couple of years later, and I wasn't about to forego any of the fun.

None of the hand flying I did was prohibited by our ops specs of the time. My question is: to what degree, if any, do current ops specs discourage or prohibit the hand flying I did?

Comment: It's good to see that hand flying skills are [still in use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHJuFsp_w8I).  A great display of stick and rudder skills.

Answer (score 13):

There are no Ops Specs that preclude hand flying, however company policy and operational considerations do in specific situations:

- Level flight within RVSM airspace
- Cat III approaches (and I believe Cat II approaches)
- High workload, critical phases of flight (company specific policies here)

The FAA even came out with a [SAFO](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2013/SAFO13002.pdf) not too long ago recommending that pilots do more hand flying during periods of low workload (and during training) with the goal of maintaining hand flying proficiency.

Comment: i thought using the autopilot in level flight within RVSM was required by regs

Comment: @rbp It is, and falls under "operational considerations". ;-)

Answer (score 12):

My company only mandated autopilot use during monitored approaches (all cat II approaches and cat I below RVR 2400 for high minimums captains) and for compliance with RVSM ops.

I typically hand flew at least up to 10,000 feet but often up into the flight levels.  On descent into fields with a lot of vectoring I usually disconnected the autopilot on our final vector to intercept the approach.  Going into less busy places I often disconnected the autopilot when descending out of 10,000 feet.

I also tried to get in one raw-data (no autopilot, no flight director) ILS approach every trip I flew to keep those skills up.